# Regex in python seems to be not working with some hyphen

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse some dates with following regex. But it seems to be working with some hyphens only. Please have a look at the link below. It is not matching some dates. I added that particular hyphen, but it works only in rgex101.com. Not in Python.

```
((?:(?<= )|^)((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])?[/-] ?(?:[12][0-9])?[0-9]{2})\b(?:[\s-]+)[/-]{0,2}\s*\b((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]) ?[/-] ?(?:[12][0-9])?[0-9]{2})\b)
```

https://regex101.com/r/vI6qN1/1

Comment: Note that `[0-9]` is equivalent to `\d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add **multiline modifier**.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?m)((?:(?<= )|^)((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])?[/-] ?(?:[12][0-9])?[0-9]{2})\b(?:[\s-]+)[/-]{0,2}\s*\b((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]) ?[/-] ?(?:[12][0-9])?[0-9]{2})\b)', s)
[('02/2003-01/2005', '02/2003', '01/2005'), ('01/2002-01/2003', '01/2002', '01/2003'), ('01/2005-02/2007', '01/2005', '02/2007'), ('02/2003-01/2005', '02/2003', '01/2005'), ('01/2002-01/2003', '01/2002', '01/2003'), ('03/1999-01/2002', '03/1999', '01/2002')]
```

Whenever anchors are used, it's better to add multiline modifier.

**Example:**

```
>>> s = """     01/2013-11/2014
        01/2010-12/2012

        01/2009-01/2010


        03/2007-12/2009


 02/2003-01/2005

01/2002-01/2003


01/2005-02/2007  

 02/2003-01/2005, 

 01/2002-01/2003, 


, 03/1999-01/2002,
"""
>>> re.findall(r'((?:(?<= )|^)((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])?[/-] ?(?:[12][0-9])?[0-9]{2})\b(?:[\s-]+)[/-]{0,2}\s*\b((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]) ?[/-] ?(?:[12][0-9])?[0-9]{2})\b)', s)
[('02/2003-01/2005', '02/2003', '01/2005'), ('02/2003-01/2005', '02/2003', '01/2005'), ('01/2002-01/2003', '01/2002', '01/2003'), ('03/1999-01/2002', '03/1999', '01/2002')]
>>> re.findall(r'(?m)((?:(?<= )|^)((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])?[/-] ?(?:[12][0-9])?[0-9]{2})\b(?:[\s-]+)[/-]{0,2}\s*\b((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]) ?[/-] ?(?:[12][0-9])?[0-9]{2})\b)', s)
[('02/2003-01/2005', '02/2003', '01/2005'), ('01/2002-01/2003', '01/2002', '01/2003'), ('01/2005-02/2007', '01/2005', '02/2007'), ('02/2003-01/2005', '02/2003', '01/2005'), ('01/2002-01/2003', '01/2002', '01/2003'), ('03/1999-01/2002', '03/1999', '01/2002')]
```

<sub>See there is a difference in match results.</sub>

Comment: You could add the multiline modifier by `re.MULTILINE` param.

Comment: If you look at my code in https://regex101.com/r/vI6qN1/1 I have added "gmi" parameter there. It represents multiline . I will check your code.

Comment: Hi avinash , have a look at this link https://regex101.com/r/bQ0mM3/1 . Its your code in regex101.com

Comment: Its is not matching some.

Comment: how about this https://regex101.com/r/bQ0mM3/2 ? the reason is because there is a tab exists before that dates not spaces.

Comment: I understood. May be this is a blunt question. Doesn't "\s" covers all type of spaces if there (including tab). Its hard to find these spaces manually which category they belongs to.

Comment: but `\s` matches newline characters also. To avoid line breaks, you could use `(?:(?![\r\n])\s)*`